# Being blocked while scraping Instagram followers with Google Sheets

Tags: web-scraping, google-sheets, instagram

I am trying to scrape the number of Instagram followers an account has via Google Spreadsheet. Actually the formula worked, but when I copied it a couple of thousand cells, it stopped working. I guess I have been blocked by Instagram, because it was to many queries in too short a time.

Is there any way to bypass this?

Comment: Previously I was trying similar thing with my University network. Decided to see if same file exists within server. Started looking for all links in format `mm/yyyy` by trial and error, after 30ish queries University blocked my IP automatically. I've put 800ms delay, everything went perfectly normal. You can try to add some delay between queries, yes it will extend the time required but it will make the job done. (If query limitation is the only barrier.)

Answer (score 1):

Instagram has probably recognised that a very high number of requests are coming from your IP address and simply blocked that address.

To get around the block, you can change your IP address through a vpn or a proxy connection. However as soon as you attempt to scrape for followers again you will almost certainly be blocked again.

Instagram is probably doing this automatically. The only way to do this sort of scraping and go undetected is to spread the requests to Instagram out. This can be done over many different computers / IP addresses, or by adding a delay between the requests. You will potentially need something more powerful than Google sheets to accomplish that however.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I already suspected this.
Does anybody know if the block will be repealed at some time?

Comment: No idea. I would assume not. There are many ways to change your IP address to get around this however.