# Requests in python sometimes works and sometimes not

Tags: python, instagram

I was trying to create an instagram post downloader bot with python:

```
import requests
import re

#get url's detail
def get_response(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    while r.status_code != 200:
        r = requests.get(url)
    return r.text

def prepare_urls(matches):
    return list({match.replace("\\u0026", "&") for match in matches})

url = input('Enter Instagram URL: ')
response = get_response(url)

#check if there is video url or picture url in the json webpage that is opened
vid_matches = re.findall('"video_url":"([^"]+)"', response)
pic_matches = re.findall('"display_url":"([^"]+)"', response)

vid_urls = prepare_urls(vid_matches)
pic_urls = prepare_urls(pic_matches)

if vid_urls:
    print('Detected Videos:\n{0}'.format('\n'.join(vid_urls)))

if pic_urls:
    print('Detected Pictures:\n{0}'.format('\n'.join(pic_urls)))

if not (vid_urls or pic_urls):
    print('Could not recognize the media in the provided URL.')
```

After I finished the code, I tried it with a video link and it worked . After 1 hour I tried the same video link but it prints third condition :"Could not recognize the media in the provided URL.".
I'm confused . As you see , I never used my login credentials in the code but first time it works and second time not works...
Any ideas?

Comment: Your *get_response()* function is seriously flawed. If, the *status_code* is anything other than 200 your code will loop indefinitely in the hope that the server will change its mind. That's just wishful thinking. Some status code are worth retrying but they are in the minority of possible responses

Answer (score 0):

Make it so that each URL ends with the string "?__a=1"   (When I have some free time, I'll edit this post and add the exact command to append the string to the URL's end.)

For example, instead of:
https://www.instagram.com/p/CECsuu2BgXj/

It should be:
https://www.instagram.com/p/CECsuu2BgXj/?__a=1

Output:

```
Detected Videos:
https://instagram.fdet1-2.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t50.2886-16/117817389_1889475617843249_1329686959743847420_n.mp4?efg=eyJ2ZW5jb2RlX3RhZyI6InZ0c192b2RfdXJsZ2VuLjcyMC5jbGlwcy5kZWZhdWx0IiwicWVfZ3JvdXBzIjoiW1wiaWdfd2ViX2RlbGl2ZXJ5X3Z0c19vdGZcIl0ifQ&_nc_ht=instagram.fdet1-2.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=105&_nc_ohc=OZRYx-3yUoAAX-b1xzZ&edm=AABBvjUBAAAA&vs=17858436890092651_3299599943&_nc_vs=HBksFQAYJEdDM0FCUWN4YUFQVGQ3WUdBUHhMQUxJXy0zTVNicV9FQUFBRhUAAsgBABUAGCRHQ0hOQ2dkbFlrcEYwOWtDQUtHQ0RqWUV4cGdzYnFfRUFBQUYVAgLIAQAoABgAGwAVAAAm1onK7OqJuT8VAigCQzMsF0AkmZmZmZmaGBJkYXNoX2Jhc2VsaW5lXzFfdjERAHX%2BBwA%3D&ccb=7-4&oe=6200F187&oh=00_AT-WTSxaoeTOd_GO0gMtqSqkgRXtxibffFG5pJGyCOPTNQ&_nc_sid=83d603
Detected Pictures:
https://instagram.fdet1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-15/e35/117915347_192544875567579_944852773653606759_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fdet1-1.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=103&_nc_ohc=0Bdvog7HWe8AX-3vsql&edm=AABBvjUBAAAA&ccb=7-4&oh=00_AT_O33BzV3tCKaDp_9eqeBUiYgyzVguImltLTuPIPKP4hg&oe=6201035F&_nc_sid=83d603
```

For more info, check out [this awesome post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49341049/18084172).

Comment: Thanks but this doesnt work for https://www.instagram.com/p/CZllGtULjuz/

Comment: Ah, I see. I checked on my browser, and indeed I get a login page more often than not. Looks like this is happening server side. I'm afraid that authenticating as a guest is unreliable, and even with login, [Instagram can ban your IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50530205/18084172) if it's sending too many requests. Sorry I can't be of more help, but [Instagram is cracking down hard.](https://proxy.vulpes.one/gemini/cadence.moe/gemlog/2020-12-17-future-of-bibliogram.bliz) You can potentially consider Bibliogram, it still works okay despite Instagram's constant bans.